# How do I cancel once() manually in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have this schema:

```
{
  "movies": {
    "movie-id-1": {
      "title": "Rambo no. 5",
      "description": "",
      "genre": "genre-id-1"
    }
  },
  "genres": {
    "genre-id-1": {
      "name": "Action",
      "description": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I need to start a `child_added` listener on `/movies`:

```
const onMovieChildAdded = ref.child('movies').on('child_added', (movieSnap) => {
  const movie = movieSnap.val()

  ref.child(`genres/${movie.genre}`).once('value').then((genreSnap) => {
    const genre = genreSnap.val()
    console.log(movie.title, genre.name)
  })
})
```

In the above code, if a new movie is added to the list, I also perform another query that retrieves its genre. Question is, if I turn off the `child_added` listener:

```
ref.child('movies').off('child_added', onMovieChildAdded)
```

How do I cancel the `once('value')` inside as well?

Because sometimes the `once('value')` callback still gets called even after turning off `child_added`.

Comment: "once" should only get called...once.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, the .once() method will automatically stop listening once the data arrives. You don't have to call .off().

Comment: I know about that. But I want it to cancel i.e. not continue to execute the callback after I call `.off('child_added')`. Is there a way to cancel it? Or since it's a promise, there's no way to cancel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `once` call will always resolve, as JavaScript does not provide a way to cancel in-flight asynchronous actions. You would instead want to immediately return from the `once` callback instead of taking any action if the "cancel" has happened elsewhere.

You could signal this by, for instance, setting a `canceled` variable to `true` when you cancel and, inside the callback, doing:

```
if (canceled) return;
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way. I read about promises being not cancelable.